# How to create ASP.net identity tables in an already created database using code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

My application has been in development for about a month. I now decided to use ASP.NET Identity. I already have the view models for identity but need to create the tables. I was thinking and I am not exactly sure why I do not have the tables already if I have the view models?? I have drop create on in the initializer with my own custom context, I just need to know how to get EF to build the included Identity tables for users and roles? I looked around and none of the posted answers seem to be what I need?

Comment: If you want to just run SQL scripts instead of using EF Migrations you could check [my public gist for AspNetCore Identity + IdentityServer4 SQL scripts](https://gist.github.com/jeroenheijmans/8fa79427abc25a864cb055616644172f).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after a bit of reading a fiddling i got the answer. All I had to do was finally run the register method from ASP.NET Identity and all the tables were created.

Comment: What is this Register method? Is it on the Account Controller?

Comment: Note:  depending on your setup the tables may create in a local database file.

Comment: I ran into the same problem but I am not sure I understand your solution

Comment: I tried to register a user running through Account Controller's Register method my  application noticed that database structure is not there and seeded it for me.

I think it's what LeRainman refers to

Answer (score 16):

**Consider Migrations**

If applicable, you need to consider building a [migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx), which will allow you to generate (and potentially execute) the necessary scripts to create the appropriate tables or changes within your database.

By default, you should have some type of `ApplicationDbContext` class that looks like the following which will be used to define your "security-related" database:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", false)
    {
    }

    // Other code omitted for brevity
}
```

You'll then just need to run the **Enable-Migrations** command in Package Manager Console:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

This should generate a Migrations folder within your application that contains various configuration files that control how migrations are preformed as well as an `InitialCreate` migration.  This may only be present if you previously had some Code-First related code within your application, if not, don't worry about it. You can then try running the **Update-Database** command, which should execute any migrations (including an initial one) against your database:

```
Update-Database
```

Once your database has been updated, you can continue to make changes to your model and simply create and execute new migrations through the **Add-Migration** command and the previous Update-Database command:

```
Add-Migration "AddedAnotherPropertyToFoo"
Update-Database
```

Comment: I do know about migrations, I was just trying to find a way to get the tables created without the migrations. Is this not possible if the database is already created?

Comment: You can find scripts in [this blog post](https://danieleagle.com/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/) that you could use to generate the necessary identity-related tables without using migrations I suppose. The post essentially just generates the tables automatically and then the author scripts out each one (e.g. users, roles, etc.) that you could execute on your own.

Comment: Emphasis on inheriting from IdentityDbContext. This is needed for the identity tables to show up during the migration.

Comment: That command is not recognized

Comment: Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations. Although it does not refer to this topic, it will be an interesting requirement to maintain later

Answer (score 7):

Run this SQL Script on your database and get it done.

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetRoles]    Script Date: 15-Mar-17 10:27:06 PM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles](

    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

    [Id] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]



GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]    Script Date: 15-Mar-17 10:27:06 PM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims](

    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

    [Id] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]



GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]    Script Date: 15-Mar-17 10:27:06 PM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](

    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

    [LoginProvider] ASC,

    [ProviderKey] ASC,

    [UserId] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]



GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]    Script Date: 15-Mar-17 10:27:06 PM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](

    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    [RoleId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

    [UserId] ASC,

    [RoleId] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]



GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUsers]    Script Date: 15-Mar-17 10:27:06 PM ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](

    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,

    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,

    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,

    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,

    [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,

    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,

    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,

    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

(

    [Id] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]



GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])

REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])

ON DELETE CASCADE

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])

REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])

ON DELETE CASCADE

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])

REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id])

ON DELETE CASCADE

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])

REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])

ON DELETE CASCADE

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]

GO
```

Comment: What version does this support? Where did you get this from?

Comment: This script works with old MVC. I got it from a database created by new web application with authentication.

Comment: i think automated way is asked. also what code is changed, your sql will be same and older version

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just run the ASP.NET Identity Sql Scripts against the database if you do not want to Enable Migrations:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/677279/SQL-script-for-creating-an-ASP-NET-Identity-Databa

Comment: Is it not possible to generate the tables from the command line in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If you finally have migrations enabled in your project, you can add a new one and run it against your database:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Shared.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class NuevoIdentity : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "EmailIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedEmail");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
}
```

This migration will create the tables corresponding to Identity from code, in the same way as the SQL script.

This is only part of the process, for .NET 8 it can help you: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-with-identity-in-dotnet-8/