# How can I use Windows authentication in MVC but use the newer identity database tables for role storage?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, oracle

I'm using MVC 5 and Windows authentication, and need to use role management in a database, not AD groups. I've used the asp.net membership solution to do this in the past but would prefer to use the more modern identity table(s). I do not have access to AD groups. How can this be done?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459432/how-to-create-asp-net-identity-tables-in-an-already-created-database-using-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would skip the ASP.NET Identity part and just do it using a custom Authorization filter.

Historically the lines between Authentication (Can you prove *who* you are) and Authorization (What are you *allowed* to do) have been quite blurred in MVC.

When you have Windows authentication enabled, the *Authentication* part is taken care of, and the users' identity in the form of Domain\Username is already set against the `HttpContext`. What you need to do is figure out what they are *Authorized* for.

The question is tagged as Oracle, and you may wish to use caching or something similar, so the exact method will vary. For simplicity we will assume that you have a static `UserManager.IsInRole` class / method that takes a Domain\Username and a comma separated Roles string to check and returns a bool indicating if the user is in one of the allowed roles. In practice you may need to mess about with Dependency Injection which can be a bit tricky with filters.

```
public class DbAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);

        var user = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity;

        if (user == null)
            return false;

        return isAuthorized && UserManager.IsInRole(user.Name, this.Roles);
    }
}
```

This can then be used in place of the standard `Authorize` attribute on Controllers or Actions of your Choice

Comment: Great answer, I think this may work. I've had to switch to Oracle Identity vs. AD, but have other areas where this will fit perfectly. Thank you!