# How IdentityDbContext adds its tables to an existing database at runtime?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

I've read all the below questions (and more)

- [How to add new table to existing database code first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23662755/7261242)
- [How to create ASP.net identity tables in an already created database using code first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43459432/2300466)
- [Entity Framework - How to check if table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6100969/2300466)

---

I want to know how `IdentityDbContext` adds its tables (AspNetUsers, AspNetUserLogins, etc.) to an existing database on the first application run.

I don't think they use any of [these mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6100969/2300466) to check if a table exists then apply a migration if not.

Is there any reference to the source code they use ?

**Note**:

I ask because I have multiple `DbContext`s in my application, and I want to (find a **database-independent** solution to) add only the db tables that the user will need at runtime.

Comment: It does use the same mechanisms (Models, DbSets, etc). They are in the base classes so you don't see the code. If you point to a blank database it will create the identity tables unless you have a null initializer. Adding migrations will also generate the tables.

Comment: @SteveGreene I know they use Models, DbSets, etc. but what else do they do for adding their tables at runtime to an existing db ?.. When I use 2 normal DbContexts for the same db, the first one creates the database and the second one throws an exception complains that the db has been changed since the model created.

Comment: You could just use a single context that inherits from IdentityDbContext. If that is not possible, then set your initializers to null or MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion and use migrations.